# Resource manager class in C++

Tags: resources, lxc, cgroups, setrlimit

I am currently implementing a server program that forks a process to handle a client's request. The forked process must be well-controlled in terms of cpu, memory, disk, and other system attributes. I noticed the easiest way to implement a resource manager class is to wrap around C `rlimit`. However, `rlimit` seems too basic. I was informed modern software technology such as `cgroups` and `LXC` can also do good jobs. In my applications, the forked processes must communicate with each other, either through local shared memory or remote network socket (the application runs on a machine cluster). In this case, is `cgroups` or `LXC` affordable? I noticed that a container is fully isolated and cannot talk to each other. Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: What I understand from your question is the necessity to control resource utilization of your forked processes. Should you use containers for each forked process? I don't think so. What you can do is to create a `'lxc` container that runs the root parent server instance and forks new processes on new client requests. Now, each of those newly forked processes' resources can be control through `/sys/fs/cgroup/` filesystem.

Comment: But you have to first reason the need to create `lxc` container for your root server instance. Are you going to run different servers on your machine ? If no, then you are better off running the root server instance on your host execution without `lxc` and still be able to control forked processes' resource utilization using `cgroup` filesystem

Comment: This link should help you with `cgroup` workings https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt